# Flutter how to show a list of Button inside a Pop Up on a Button tap

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my flutter app, I want to get a list of buttons inside a popup when a button is tapped. In that list, I wish to have buttons which when clicked should edit a Text widget that I used in my app
Any suggestion for this??

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert check this plugin to make a popup alert easily
you may use a Column in alert for buttons, on tapping these may setState value to edit enable edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use the `dialog`

On a button click show dialog as -

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => Button(),
          );
```

Check this also [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)